# How can i prefill calendly guests email?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendly

i passed the prefill data using `initPopupWidget`.

```
window?.Calendly.initPopupWidget({
  url: schedulePageUrl,
  prefill: {
    email: auth.email,
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    name: "",
    guests: ["test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"],
  },
});
```

But the form is empty, `email` is populated successfully. Also i clicked the `Add Guests` button to open the **Guest Email(s)** filed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `guests` prefill value should be a string of comma separated values. You can update your code to the following to resolve this issue:

```
window?.Calendly.initPopupWidget({
  url: schedulePageUrl,
  prefill: {
    email: auth.email,
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    name: "",
    guests: ["test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"].join(','),
  },
});
```

Comment: no, it is not working

Comment: I just looked at the embed script provided by Calendly (https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js) and it appears that the script only uses the following prefill values - ["name","firstName","lastName","email"]. As a result, the guests value is ignored. 

You'll need to add the guests parameter to the url property.


url: schedulePageUrl + '?guests=' + ["test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"].join(',')